# cant access info data outside of its scope: transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info, callback){

Tags: node.js, scope, closures, ip-address

I am trying to get ip address from (i guess) the built-in returns of transporter.sendMail after found out the info built-in return carries ip-address. I have to get ip this way is because the normal var ip = req.clientIp; way only output ::1.

I spent a lot of time fixing that but I could not. Then I read a lot of post on stack overflow about closure because my problem is similar to that but after days of read and try I found out It is not the same at all. some of the solutions worked only in a pure closure thing but when I move it to my case/code It does not work at all.

The problem is the info only exist in its scope (or only exist within the callback function) I can log out the info data but I cant pass it out as a variable so I can use it outside of that scope. The variable carrying info's data will be undefined, if you try to print it out outside of the scope.

It is because node.js will run all other codes besides functions first so If functions did not get read first then even I put the code calling the variable after the function, the variable will still be undefined because the info does not exist outside of the function. Even if I try to call the function before I call the variable and pass the info out, I cant pass the variable out or at least before I call the variable.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'Gmail',
            //var info=info.response,
            auth: {
                user: 'xxxxx', // Your email id
                pass: 'xxxxx' // Your password
            }//auth
        });//transporter=nodemailer.create

      var mailOptions={
        to: 'xxxxxx',
        subject: req.body,
        //subject: "lt",
        text: "Email Test Has Passed"
      }//mailOptions

      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info, callback){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.json({yo: 'error'});
        }else{
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
            //console.log('info sent: ' + info);//[obj obj]
            infor=info.response;
            res.json({yo: info.response});
        };//else
      });//();//transporter.sendmail(mailoptions)

    res.render('index', { 
        title: 'laundrytake: we clean and deliver your laundry/dry cleaning',
        page:'Home',
    });//atw is a local var inside the temp index feeded from myArtwork    
});//router.get(/)
```

Here is what I ve tried. I like to keep track what I ve done in comments

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var infor;
    var func;
    //var func={};
    // var p=req.ip;

    // inside middleware handler 
    // var ipMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
    //     var clientIp = requestIp.getClientIp(req); 
    //     next();
    // };
    // ipMiddleware;

    // on localhost you'll see 127.0.0.1 if you're using IPv4  
    // or ::1, ::ffff:127.0.0.1 if you're using IPv6

    // app.use(requestIp.mw())

    // app.use(function(req, res) {
    //     var ip = req.clientIp;
    //     res.end(ip);
    // });

    // var ip;
    // if (req.headers['x-forwarded-for']) {
    //     ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'].split(",")[0];
    // } else if (req.connection && req.connection.remoteAddress) {
    //     ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    // } else {
    //     ip = req.ip;
    // }console.log("client IP is *********************" + ip);

    // var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
    // if (ip.substr(0, 7) == "::ffff:") {
    // ip = ip.substr(7)
    // }
    // console.log("client IP is:");
    // console.log(ip);

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'Gmail',
            //var info=info.response,
            auth: {
                user: 'xxxxx', // Your email id
                pass: 'xxxxx' // Your password
            }//auth
        });//transporter=nodemailer.create

        // console.log("xxx");
        //var text = 'Hello world from \n\n' + req.body.name;

      var mailOptions={
        to: 'xxxxxx',
        subject: req.body,
        //subject: "lt",
        text: "Email Test Has Passed"
      }//mailOptions

      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info, callback){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.json({yo: 'error'});
        }else{
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
            //console.log('info sent: ' + info);//[obj obj]
            infor=info.response;
            res.json({yo: info.response});
            // app.locals.infor=info.response;
            //return(infor, //log infor dnt fix 
            //console.log("ff"));//ff printout in the end
            //callback(infor);//log infor dnt fix //log r [f sendmail]
            //return function(){return infor};//log r [f sendmail]. with info involk })(info);info undef, with 3 or () involk tran.sendM(...)not a f
            //sign(info.response);//no print out 
            // return (
            //     function(){
            //         //infor=info.response;
            //         console.log("out :");
            //     }
            // )//}
            // func=(function() { //create a new scope using a wrapper function
            // var ilocal = info.response; //capture i into a local var
            // return function() { //return the inner function
            //     console.log("My value: " + ilocal);
            //  };//return f()
            // })();//f()
        };//else
      });//();//transporter.sendmail(mailoptions)

    //function sign (ff){var xx=ff; console.log(ff);}
    // ino=transporter.sendMail();
    // ino.out;
    //ff //ff() //ff not def return(func ff(){var xx=info.res})
    var sign = function( infor ) {//no callback unhandled promise rejec warning no recipients def err 
        console.log("User: " + infor + " is saved successfully.")
    };
    var r =transporter.sendMail;//infor: [f: sendMail] undef
    //transporter.sendMail( sign );//callback(infor) nothing inside sendMail warning
    //transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, sign );//user: null is saved succ
    console.log("infor :"); 
    console.log(infor);
    console.log(r);
    //console.log(info.response);//info not def
    //func();//not a f

    res.render('index', { 
        title: 'laundrytake: we clean and deliver your laundry/dry cleaning',
        page:'Home',
    });//atw is a local var inside the temp index feeded from myArtwork    
});//router.get(/)
```

Comment: I ve read hoisting, javascript asynchronous nature, IIFE ... I think It has something to do with the nature of the transporter.sendMail or more precisely nodemailer.createTransport 's sendMail method/property

Answer (score 0):

```html
$( window ).load(function() {
  console.log("loaded");
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',//{ '"71.11.188.189"': '' }
    data: userip,//JSON.stringify(userip),//userip,//ipad
    url: '/yhu/fkip',//same err af remove sendMail from index.js /
    dataType: 'JSON' //text same print save 500 err
  }).done(function( response ) {
    console.log("ajax POST ip");//never printed 
    console.log(userip);
    if (response.msg === '') {//w/o this //POST /yhu/fkip 500(internal server err)
            console.log("res.msg null");
            }//if(response.msg)
            else {
                // If something goes wrong, alert the error message that our service returned
                alert('Error: ' + response.msg);
            }//else
  });//.done(function(response    
});//$(window).load(function
```

Comment: here is the way i am trying. next thing i ll try is to use node ejs s var feature <% %> i used it to put content out from a data file so there is data flow from back end to html therefore i think i can do it the other way transferring data from html(the script code for ip which stored in a var userip) to back end(email/db)

Comment: this code is in my html (index.ejs to be precise) once again i am trying to translate a html script code for ip into a back end code like a code in routes that way i dont have to struggle to find a way to pass the ip from html to back end since if i code it in routes then i can just use the var stores ip inside the route itself like router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {  xxxx;(code to get ip and store it in var userip)      xxxxxx;(code to send the userip to my email/db)  see how they are all done in a route